# How to return only the id of a vertex in Cosmos Graph

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am importing data from SQL Server to Cosmos Gremlin Graph. During the process, I need to search for a vertex by its old id, as the new id is needed to create an edge. I only want the id not all the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

You can use the SubmitWithSingleResultAsync( query ); method with a query like g.V().has('elementTypeId','1').has('importId',123456).properties('id').value()